# C#: About System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, .net

```
static void X(String a,String b,String c)
    {

       TextBox textBox3 = new TextBox();
                      a = textBox3.Text;

      if (a == " ")
            {

                throw new ArgumentNullException(a);
            }


      TextBox textBox4 = new TextBox();
                     b = textBox4.Text;

      if (b == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(b);
            }

      TextBox textBox5 = new TextBox();
            c = textBox5.Text;

            if (c == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(c);
            }


     }
```

private void Go2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

```
         ........//my code
            X(Sx,Sy,V);
         ........// my some code
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your String is not correct");
        }
```

}

My program cannot do System.ArgumentNullException. How can I solve this program?Please, guide.

Comment: Kindly properly format your code. string.empty is different from a == " " . Check for String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace instead.

Comment: You need to use the `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` to check the values

Comment: Why you are passing arguments to method X when you are taking it form different text boxes inside method X?It doesn't mean any sense to me?Use string.IsNullOrEmpty() inside IF blocks to compare in place of comparing it to " " or null

Comment: You are not actually checking your method arguments, and therefore should not throw ArgumentNullException.  Better to create your own specific InvalidInputValueException or similar with a descriptive message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` to check the values for your `string` variables. As you are assigning them values in your method using `textbox.Text`. They get the `string.Empty` values assigned to them. And Your if statements never evolves to `true` and they never throw the exception.
If you alter your conditions like this then that would work,

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a))
 {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("Thrown from first condition");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

to check if a string is null use the dedicated functions for this and initialize the ArgumentNullException with the parameter name and not with the parameter.

For example instead of

```
if (a == " ")
            {

                throw new ArgumentNullException(a);
            }
```

write

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a))
                {

                    throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
                }
```

for

```
if (c == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(c);
            }
```

write

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("c");
            }
```

Comment: IMHO, IsNullOrWhiteSpace, and IsNullOrEmpty should lead to ArgumentException, not ArgurmentNullException.

Comment: Your right for IsNullOrWhiteSpace, but for IsNullOrEmpty it's a matter of context ;) Normally I throw ArgumentNullException for if(c == null) but Thiha Lion ask about ArgumentNullException.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of :

```
    throw new ArgumentNullException(c);
    catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your String is not correct");
    }
```

This :

```
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Your String is not correct");
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Catching a general Exception is bad practice..

Comment: so you can change "Exception ex" to "ArgumentNullException ex"